# How to prevent HTML form from submit if I click another button inside the form?

Tags: javascript, html, button, addeventlistener, form-submit

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id = "myForm">
 <div>     
      <div><p><label for = "myText"><b>Article Text </b></label>
      <button type = "button" id="boldBtn">Bold</button></p></div>
      <textarea name ="myText" id = "myText" rows="20" cols="55"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div>
      <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg"  value = "Submit">
 </div>
</form>
```

And this is the javascript code:

```
const myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
const myText = document.getElementById('myText');
const boldBtn = document.getElementById('boldBtn');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(myForm);
     //..............
     //code to send data to PHP
});

boldBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    //insertAtCursor(myText,"BOLD text here");
});
```

I want to add a button that inserts Bold tags inside the textArea but when I click the Bold Button it submits the form. I understand that it might be doing this because I have the submit event listener on the form, but each event listens for different triggers and also the button types are different.

Is there a way to make this work, and also keeping the event listener on the form element ?

If not, what is a proper solution to this problem ?

Comment: button type='button' shouldn't submit the form. are you getting an error? to test, `<form action="#" onsubmit='return false' ...`

Comment: The code works, I just forgot to refresh the page. I was just using some of my buttons return then edit, and even if I was leaving the page and then came back, the changes were not loaded. This seems the most reasonable explanation, because I didn't change something in the code and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. I have added your code into a snippet and clicking the bold button will not be submitted. So, what you show us is correct. Something else is causing your problem, some other code does the submit that you did not share. Please open the Dev Tools, click on the Network tab and click on the bold button in my snippet. Do you see a new line there representing a submit? If not, then the code you show is correct and something else is causing the problem. You will need to debug the Javascript you already have.

```html
<form action="#" method="POST" id = "myForm">
 <div>     
      <div><p><label for = "myText"><b>Article Text </b></label>
      <button type = "button" id="boldBtn">Bold</button></p></div>
      <textarea name ="myText" id = "myText" rows="20" cols="55"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div>
      <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg"  value = "Submit">
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are right! The code was good, and I think the problem was that I forgot to refresh the page. I was clicking only on some return and then edit buttons. The most obvious problem was that the JavaScript/HTML changes were not all loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your problem you have many error in your javascript function , yo need define your function insertCursor .

Check this codepen :

```js
var myForm = document.getElementById('myform');
var myText = document.getElementById('myText');
var boldBtn = document.getElementById('boldBtn');

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(myForm);
     //..............
     //code to send data to PHP
});

function insertAtCursor(Item,value){
  Item.value=value;
}
boldBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    insertAtCursor(myText,"BOLD text here");
});
```

```html
<form action="#" method="POST" id="myform">
 <div>     
      <div><p><label for = "myText"><b>Article Text </b></label>
      <button type = "button" id="boldBtn">Bold</button></p></div>
      <textarea name ="myText" id = "myText" rows="20" cols="55"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div>
      <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg"  value = "Submit">
 </div>
</form>
```

Thx

Comment: :)) I have the function defined, I just didn't write it here because that was not my problem. But thanks anyway!

Comment: The code was good. Because I was using some buttons on the page to navigate between pages, I think not all the HTML/Javascript changes loaded and I didn't check the page source to see the problem. After I made a page refresh all worked, without any code changes.